# php DateTime object comparison

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have simple DateTime lesson. I'm comparing the 2 DateTime objects and they dont work right. I've tried swapping things around and it still fails. It fails when I enter the current date manually, even if the date is the same. I have to enter a date manually though. Thanks for any help. Heres the function:

```
function dtcompare(){
    //I make the date the same as the current 
    //date and it doesnt echo that its equal. 
    $date1 = new DateTime('5/9/2015'); //a date entered
    $date2 = new DateTime(); //the current date
    $mdy = 'n/j/Y'; //the format

    if($date1 == $date2){

        echo "d1 == d2"; //This should be echoing
    }
    elseif($date1  > $date2){

        echo "d1 > d2";
    }
    elseif($date1 < $date2){        

        echo "    d1 < d2    "; //but this always echos
    }
  }
```

I changed everything to make format comparisons, but now the lowest date echos even when I put in a future date. Heres what happens:

```js
function dtcompare(){
    
     
    $date1 = new DateTime('5/18/2015'); //a future date
    $date2 = new DateTime(); //the current date
    $mdy = 'n/j/Y'; //the format
    
    if($date1->format($mdy) == $date2->format($mdy)){
   
        echo "d1 == d2";
    }
    elseif($date1->format($mdy)  > $date2->format($mdy)){
        //This will echo if the date is in the next month 6/1/2015    
        echo "d1 > d2";
    }
    elseif($date1->format($mdy) < $date2->format($mdy)){        
   
        //This echos even though it's not 5/18/2015 yet!        
        echo $date1->format($mdy)."d1 < d2".$date2->format($mdy); 
    }
  }
```

I've been playing with this, and I got it to work by using some of both. I think this is not the way its supposed to work and might cause problems with some other date now that im unaware of. Heres what I did:

```js
function dtcompare(){
    
    $date1 = new DateTime('5/12/2015'); //a future date
    $date2 = new DateTime(); //the current date
    $mdy = 'n/j/Y'; //the format
  
  
    //Using the datetime->format for == comparisons and the other
    //way for datetimes greater or less than. This works, but I think this is NOT
    //how this should work though. It feels like a rig for something that
    //should work one way (DateTime->format() comparison) or another (DateTime comparison w.o format)
    if($date1->format($mdy) == $date2->format($mdy)){
        echo 'date1 and date2 have the same date and time';
    }
    elseif($date1 > $date2){
        echo 'date1 > date2 meaning its a later date and time';
    }
    elseif($date1 < $date2){
        echo 'date1 < date2 meaning its an earlier date and time';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you defined your format in which you want to compare your two [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)'s, but you didn't used it.

Just use [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) with your format variable when you compare the two DateTimes's otherwise also secons and minutes, just  everything gets compared.

```
if($date1->format($mdy) == $date2->format($mdy)){
       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ See here, to just compare month, day and year
    echo "d1 == d2"; //This should be echoing
}
elseif($date1->format($mdy)  > $date2->format($mdy)){

    echo "d1 > d2";
}
elseif($date1->format($mdy) < $date2->format($mdy)){        

    echo "    d1 < d2    "; //but this always echos
}
```

**EDIT:**

This should work for you, you have to first format your date and then take the timestamp, like this:

```
$mdy = 'n/j/Y'; //the format
$date1 = strtotime((new DateTime('5/18/2015'))->format($mdy));
$date2 = strtotime((new DateTime())->format($mdy));


if($date1 == $date2){
    echo "d1 == d2";
} elseif($date1  > $date2) {
    echo "d1 > d2";
} elseif($date1 < $date2){        
    echo $date1."d1 < d2".$date2; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated with what you suggest, but the DateTime object says the greater date (5/18/2015) is lower than today's date (5/9/2015). This same comparison works if I compare w.o using $date->format(). Shouldnt it work either way?

Comment: @Zapp Yes just format it as you want the dates and then you can compare them

Comment: @Zapp updated my answer now. Before the order of your format made a difference, because it compared the string, so now just take the timestamp and it should all work fine

Comment: This works, but those arent DateTime objects. Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: @Zapp No, the format() returns a string, and then the strtotime returns an int. So you end up with a integer. If you still want to save the DateTime object. just save the format and strtotime in another variable

Comment: I think this should work with DateTime objects, and I might have to do this with DateTime objects only. I'll find out and update soon. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Zapp If you only want to compare a specific format you will have to take the format and then the timestamp, there is no way around it!

Answer (score 1):

Use formatting of Date first and then compare, as you cant compare 2 objects of date Directly

Use:

```
   <?php

  //I make the date the same as the current 
    //date and it doesnt echo that its equal. 
    $date1 = new DateTime('5/9/2015'); //a date entered
    $date2 = new DateTime(); //the current date
    $mdy = 'n/j/Y'; //the format

$date1New = $date1->format('d-m-y');
$date2New = $date2->format('d-m-y');

////echo '<br> --2'.$date2;

    if($date1New == $date2New){

        echo "d1 == d2"; //This should be echoing
    }
    elseif($date1New  > $date2New){

        echo "d1 > d2";
    }
    elseif($date1New < $date2New){        

        echo "    d1 < d2    "; //but this always echos
    }

   ?>
```

Comment: This same comparison works if I compare w.o using $date->format(). But that causes my original problem with == comparison. Shouldnt it work either way?

Answer (score 0):

php DateTime already has the ability to output a unixtimestamp. So you can just compare like this:

```
$early = new DateTime( "now" );
$later = new DateTime( "now + 2days" );

if ( $early->format('U') < $later->format('U') ) {
    echo "you'll get this printed";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt use the 'U' option. Does that work with the rest of the comparisons?